# Parse Exception Android.net.parseException at user side

Tags: android

```
 `android.net.ParseException
 in android.net.WebAddress.<init>
 android.net.ParseException
 at android.net.WebAddress.<init>(WebAddress.java:109)
 at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadStarted(BrowserFrame.java:393)
 at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.nativeLoadData(Native Method)
 at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadData(BrowserFrame.java:317)
 at
 android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1012)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:641)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)`
```

We deal with the many solution of the stack overflow ,And we tasted our application on Android version 2.2, 2.3 , 4.0.4 and 4.2.2
We didnt get this crash but client side this crash occur,So please provide the solution for this following crash`

Comment: Please provide the solution ASAP

Comment: what is the value that you pass to the WebAddress constructor? It is probably not a valid web address.

Comment: Can you please tell how can we create a WebAddress constructor

Comment: Because in our application we just use WebView.......and one more thing we are not getting this error this error is client side........and we are not able to find what is th exact problem

Comment: Please provide the reason .......why this error is occuring in android

Comment: webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);
  webview.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "interface");
  webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "contactSupport");
  // webview.setClickable(false);
  webview.setFocusable(true);

Comment: In this form we use webView in android:---

Comment: In this form we use webview in android                                                      WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/ParseException.java Have a look into this

Comment: I follow this link but how can we use this in our code....reply Asap

Comment: What is the URL that you are trying to view in your WebView? does the user enter a URL?

Comment: No user is not entering the url.......we get that Htmldata from web uing jsonparsing and store that data into a string and after that we display that data on webView..

Comment: Mainly this error occurring with device Huawei U8665

Comment: Can any one please tell me what happen when we upgrade Huawei U8665 .........Reply ASAP